# Org-mode: disable abbrev-mode in source blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, abbrev

I use org-mode to write an executable paper, combining text and code. I make use of abbrev-mode to insert text more efficiently (e.g. type 'bc' to insert 'because') and to correct spelling errors. Is there any way to switch off abbrev-mode in the source blocks to prevent it expanding my variables?

I did run into [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55944/disable-minor-mode-inside-source-blocks) post, but don't see how to use that for my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way might be like this, where expansion only occurs conditionally. Put this statement in an init file, or in an org-mode hook function and you should not get expansion in src-blocks.

```
(setq abbrev-expand-function (lambda ()
                   (unless (org-in-src-block-p)
                 (abbrev--default-expand))))
```